# Select a folder with python json xbmc module

Tags: python, json, xbmc

I have been trying to get xbmc (raspbmc) to boot up in a particular videos folder, it currently boots up in the Videos menu (set by appearance skin settings), inside this view the is an option called Files, and inside there, there is an option called Videos (a source I set up).

It has occurred to me that it should be possible to use python's json xbmc module (which I already use to select focused items using the gpio) to instruct xbmc to select these options one after the other on boot, however I can't work out what the commands would be, such as how to focus or select a named option/source?

Any help is greatly appreciated
Thanks
Tom